# Error while using SetOAuthV2Info in Apigee edge

Tags: apigee

I need to update certain attributes of access token . I am trying to use SetOAuthV2Info policy but when I add that xml in policies folder and even if I dont add that in steps it starts to give me below error:

{"fault":{"faultstring":"Missing API proxy for Organization:;Environment:;VirtualHost:https_vhost;Application:Location;Revision:35;APIProxy:default ","detail":{"errorcode":"messaging.runtime.InternalClassificationError"}}}

Here is the policy xml which I am trying to use:


    UpdateScopeAttribute

WHen I remove this policy from steps and also delete this xml, my proxy works fine. But as long as this policy xml is there I am not able to run my proxy. Can anybody help?

Comment: Was able to find cause of this with help from product team . The apigee edge version on Management server is updated but in message processors its still having older version. This policy is added recently so at the run time its failing to find schema definition for this policy in Message Processors.

Answer (score 0):

You will see the 'Missing API proxy for Organization' fault most of the times whenever your step name and the name in the proxy definition doesn't match.

Comment: Was able to find cause of this with help from product team . The apigee edge version on Management server is updated but in message processors its still having older version. This policy is added recently so at the run time its failing to find schema definition for this policy in Message Processors.